# <li> padding-left in ie 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, html-lists

I have a very weired problem with indents of list elements in IE 7. Padding-left does not seem to have any effect. My html is here http://pastebin.com/0TXXN3AZ. (The list elements are supposed to be a simple navigation on the left.) The css is

```
ul.navigation{
   width: 230px;
   padding-left:2px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}

ul.navigation li{
   padding-left:2px;
   list-style: none;
}

ul.navigation li a{
   padding-left: 2px;
   display:inline-block;
}

ul.navigation li ul{
   padding-left:2px;
   list-style: none;
}

#content{
   margin-left: 260px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

In other browsers everything looks as expected. In IE 7 the intends are way to big an the list items expand into the content area. Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced,

Andreas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you to first use the [YUI Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/), that normalizes styles for all HTML elements among all browsers, and then safely customize the elements as you wish.

In case you can't use YUI Reset CSS, the problem could be that IE 7 is using margin rather than padding for ul/li elements.

So add this before your customizations:

```
ul, li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

And then customize the ul/li elements as you wish.

Comment: That would be my guess. [This browser default stylesheet table](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm) certainly seems to show that IE7 specifically uses margin rather than padding, so adding a `margin: 0` to the existing code should do the trick. And yes, @acnb, have a read about CSS resets (I use [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/) as a base, but the YUI one is perfectly good, too. Just understand what they're doing and take from them the elements you need.)

Comment: I can't use YUI Reset CSS, but margin: 0; saved my day. Thanks a lot.